# PHP Raw data read throwing max_input_vars error

Tags: php

I have an outside resource posting json to my php script.

My code to accept the post is:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

It is throwing the error:
Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini

I did some debugging and the issue is that if the json has more then 1000 &'s in it, it trhows this error as it must think each & is a variable.

Am I pulling the data correctly using that code or is this error being caused before that because of how it was posted from the other resource?

What are my options around this on this?

Comment: Make sure the client is sending `Content-type: application/json`. PHP should only try to parse the `&` characters if it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: That did it! Do you want to post that as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will try to parse `&` characters in the input if the post was sent with a `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. When you're sending JSON, you should use `Content-type: application/json`. Then PHP won't try to parse the input into the `$_POST` array.